# Remote sh script executed in Python (Paramiko) never ends

Tags: python, bash, stdout, paramiko, stderr

Hello I have the next **sh script** in other machine like next in machine .35:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mount //X.X.X.20/home/sybase /home/sybase/

Today=$(date --date="today" +%Y%m%d)
Yesterday=$(date --date="yesterday" +%Y%m%d)

LOG=/home/sybase/Log/${Today}_query.log

echo " Arranco el cron: " $(date)  >> $LOG
echo " Export for day: " $Today >>$LOG

RemovalDay=$(date --date "-7 days" +"%Y%m%d")
echo " Removal LogFile date: " $RemovalDay >> $LOG

RemovalDay2=$(date --date "-7 days" +"%Y"-"%m"-"%d")
echo " Removal LogFile date: " $RemovalDay2 >> $LOG

# Execute two queries in 2 different Sybase servers
expect << EOF
set timeout 5000000

spawn su sybase
expect "$ "
send " dbisql -nogui -c \"uid=dba;pwd=sql;eng=store1;dbn=store1\" -host X.X.X.32 -port 2640 /home/sybase/query1.sql \r "
expect "$ "
send " dbisql -nogui -c \"uid=dba;pwd=sql;eng=store2;dbn=store2\" /home/sybase/query2.sql \r "
expect "$ "

send "exit \r "

EOF

###  Result moved to folder mounted in .20

chmod 777 /home/sybase/query.txt
mv -f /home/sybase/query.txt /home/sybase/query_${Yesterday}.txt
echo " Move file query.txt to mounted folder to be stored" $(date)  >> $LOG

### Unmounted.27 paths and delete intermediate files

echo " Deleted server2 file query2 " >> $LOG

## Remove exports from previous days -7

echo " Deleted Export File query.log " >> $LOG

## Remove logs from previous days -7

echo " Deleted Old LogFile "${RemovalDay}"_query.log " >> $LOG

echo " Deleted Old Crontab LogFile "${RemovalDay2}"_query.log " >> $LOG

umount /home/sybase/

echo " Unmounted all folders " $(date)  >> $LOG
```

If I execute locally (in the .35 machine), the **sh script query.sh is relatively fast** it takes about 10 seconds to complete and it finishes.

When I try to execute that script remotely from the another machine with ip .20 with the next python program:

```
import paramiko
import os
import time

## Connect to the store1 via SSH (paramiko)

hostname = "X.X.X.35"
port = 22
username = "user"
password = "pass"

# initialize the SSH client
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
# add to known hosts
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password, port=port)
except:
    print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
    exit()

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('bash /home/sybase/query.sh')

time.sleep(60)

# read the standard output and print it
stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
lines = stdout.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line)
# close the connection
client.close()
```

It seems to never finish it just still executing but nothing happens, the results are never exported.

However when executing the python program, if I do a ps |aux grep query.sh in the X.X.X.35 machine (where the sh script query.sh is located) I get that there is 2 lines with it:

```
ps aux | grep query.sh
```

> 35001    24672  0.0  0.0 106116  1420 ?        Ss   15:26   0:00 bash
> -c bash /home/sybase/query.sh
>
> 35001    24700  0.0  0.0 106116  1244 ?        S    15:26   0:00 bash
> /home/sybase/query.sh

It also keep executing forever.

Comment: Maybe adding an `exit` at the end of your query.sh could fix the problem as you explicit exit the ssh session

Comment: Note that this is not a "sh script", it's a _bash_ script. They're two different languages, just like C++ and C are not the same language (and naming bash scripts with `.sh` extensions is just as bad an idea as naming C++ files with `.c` is). `#!/bin/bash` at the top indicates that the script is written to be run specifically by _bash_, not by _sh_.

Comment: Anyhow, speaking to debugging your problem -- don't just look for the entry for the shell itself in the process table, look at what _children_ it has. That'll give you a strong hint about why it's hanging. `pstree -p 24672`, in the above, is a place to start.